# How to do Multiple search hint by comma separated in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my application need to do multiple search hint when i type the key word in the text box.
It should display from my DB Skills. When i type first text i can see the hint but I want to show the hint by typeing separated as comma for new key words (i.e) Java , AngularJs, ...

here is my code:

```
<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="skill for skill in skills | limitTo:8"
    class="form-control">
</div>
```

I am stuck with this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: well, your code is missing...

Answer (score 0):

I used ngtagsInput, It's useful for tagging and highlighting information right on the input box.

see the link : http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos